# Индексы в Oracle

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Для чего используют индексы в БД Oracle? В чем их преимущества?

Смотрел в гугле и в книгах по БД, но так и не понял их смысла. Везде их сравнивают с закладками в книге, так что это я уже слышал. Кто может дать толковое описание, что да как?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Сравнение с закладками в книге не совсем удачное. Скорее всего это записи библиотекаря по автору и названию книги с соответствующим указанием зала, стелажа, полки и номер ячейки на полке. С помощью этих записей библиотекарь не заставит ждать часами читателя пока не обежит всю библиотеку в поиске желаемого опуса.

Индексы в БД преследуют ту же цель - с наименьшими затратами найти искомую запись в таблице. Без индексов БД будет искать одну единственную запись указанную в `WHERE` условии читая все, действительно все без исключения, блоки данных относящиеся к данной таблице (*full table scan*).

В общем случае индекс представляет собой *B-Tree*, где начиная с корневого узла (*root node*) через веточные узлы (*branch node*) обеспечивается быстрый поиск искомых листочных записей (*leaf record*). B-Tree это не бинарное дерево, как многие считают, это сбалансированное дерево (*balanced tree*). То есть все листья находятся на одном уровне и путь прохода к ним всегда примерно одинаков.

При обращении к таблице с условием по ключу на который имеется индекс, БД читает в первую очередь индекс в поиске листочной записи содержащую искомый ключ. 
Листочная запись представляет собой пару - ключ:значение, где:

- ключ - полное значение одной или нескольких колонок из соответсвуюшей записи в таблице, т.е. по сути редундантные данные
- значение - указатель на запись в таблице (`ROWID`), по которому будет произведено считывание записи из таблицы

Если, например, есть таблица `person (fullName, birthDay, birthPlace, Notes)`, где по трём первым полям создан индекс, то листочная запись будет выглядеть где-то так:

```
Вася Пупкин|1994-04-01|пос. Простаково:AAAVLMAAMAAAEgLAAA
```

`ROWID` это закодированная в `Base64` информация o местоположению записи, которая содержит номер файла данных, номер блока данных и номер записи в блоке, и по сути является самым эффективным способом найти запись на физическом носителе.

В некоторых случаях индексы создаются автоматически, как например, для ограничения `UNIQUE`, будет создан индекс по полям, на которые определено ограничение.

Редундантность данных в индексе может иметь и положительную сторону. Например, если в выборке участвуют только колонки, которые входят в ключ индекса, то обращения к таблице вообще не будет.

Answer (score 9):

Индексы позволяют быстро находить записи. Данные индексируемых колонок находятся намного быстрее, чем в неиндексируемых. Почему нужно указывать самому, и почему база не выставляет индексы по-умолчанию? Потому что при каждой вставке или удалении данных индексы у таких колонок снова перестраиваются, что занимает время. Т.е. индексы нужно использовать у часто запрашиваемых данных и желательно в таблицах, которые не так часто меняются.

Comment: Те индекс в Oracle можно рассматривать как указатель на запись в таблице или это указатель на группу записей, например колонку?

Comment: В грубом округлении это бинарное дерево указателей на записи одной колонки

Comment: Только, видимо, не binary, а - balanced как 0xdb указал в ответе